# Why I can't open any downloaded setup.exe file on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation, setup, open

Today my friend ask me how can he run any Windows application install file, because on Windows XP, just dosen't opened.
I realy surprised, first time I thinked he just joked me, but it's true, when I tryed intall a winrar or a bittorent program, just won't opened.
He has virus killer application (avast), I disabled it, but the problem is still remin.
So how can we fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click to the setup file
2. Choose *Properties*
3. And under there, in the bottom (on security), you can find an *Unblock* button ("Tiltás feloldása") and click it, choose OK, after that you can run this file.

[image: Screenshot from the magic button]

Unfortunately, he still needs to do this with every single setup file, I didn't find a solution for this, but he finally can install programs.

Comment: This is a security setting, but you made mention, of what the error was.  We expect answers and source material to be in English

Comment: @Ramhound I dosen't find the button name in english.
Can you help me out?

Comment: That is a W7 screenshot not XP, XP does not have this button on the security tab. Are you using Windows 7 or XP?

Comment: @Moab You're wrong, obviously has this button, if not have it, why I write this anwer?
The screenshot is maybe from windows 7, but the button place is same!

Comment: Screenshot is misleading...

Comment: @Moab Nope, it's not becouse based on this image you can find that button on the place.

Comment: Yep, misleading.

Comment: Yes, for me works! The button is called "Unblock".